# Azure Function "General Settings" is missing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-functions-runtime

I've recently been messing with Azure Functions and I noticed that one of my Azure Functions is missing a configuration tab.

The tab in question is this "General Settings" and I need to change one of the settings there. Does anyone know how I can access this tab? Can I do something about it? Or at least know why this happens?

I leave below 2 prints that show the difference between two Azure Functions that I have.

**Azure Function that is missing**
[image: Azure Function that is missing]

**Tab I want to use**
[image: Tab I want to use]

I'm trying to change a platform of my az function or see the current platform.

Answer (score 2):

It will be because you have created your azure function under the "Consumption (serveless)" plan. [image]

Which doesn't have the general settings tab

[image]

But if you create an azure function with the "App service plan" you get the general settings tab

[image]

HTH

Comment: I just created a Function App to validate what you said and even in Servless the "General Settings" tab appears

Answer (score 2):

Azure Functions on Linux on the "Consumption (Serverless)" Plan do not have the "General Settings" tab.

To get the "General Settings" Tab either:

- Switch your function to an "App service plan" or "Functions Premium" Plan.
- Or change the operating system to Windows.

(At least as of today 2022-04-18)

I found this out by trying it out because I could not find any documentation or information about this feature/behavior.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31571768)

Comment: I improved the answer to make it more clear what can be done.