# Does publishing a Node.js Azure function also publish dependencies?

Tags: azure-functions

When I use Azure Functions Core Tools to publish my Node.JS function app, are all of the dependencies on my local machine bundled up and sent to Azure as part of the publish operation?

I see that some packages are ignored in the default `.funcignore` generated by `func new` but there's no blanket rule to block everything in `node_modules`.

If the behavior of `func azure functionapp publish` is to always bundle the dependencies (with the exception of the `.funcignore` things) and send them along in the package, is there ever a case where Azure will need to fetch dependencies from a package registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install packages using npm in nodejs Azure function, they gets downloaded from the web and copied into the [node_modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps#nodejs-modules) folder and Node.js will look for those packages in node_modules when you import them in your application.

When you deploy your application using `func azure functionapp publish`, the dependencies you have mentioned in the [package.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps#using-a-packagejson-file) file gets deployed along with the application to Azure.

- **package.json**: Contains configuration like a list of all the package dependencies installed, main entrypoint and the scripts.
- If you want to deploy any of the dependencies to Azure, you must include them in `package.json` file.

[image]

If you want to ignore node_modules folder, you can include node_modules in .funcignore:

[image]

- As shown below (KUDU site), node_modules folder is being ignored while deploying to Azure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I see how I can prevent `node_modules` from being published with my function app, and I have confirmed that the files are not there in KUDU.  But I'm still unclear on one part of my original question.  Will Azure ever fetch these dependencies directly if I don't publish them?  I don't see that happening.  When I exclude `node_modules` in `.funcignore` my function app does not work.

Comment: Which [OS](https://i.imgur.com/5GntYDk.png) your function app running on windows or linux?

Comment: I've tried both.  Neither seems to automatically install the dependencies.  In my Windows  app I am running `npm install` in the KUDU console but it is hanging.  Not sure that would be an answer anyway--I was really hoping Azure would install deps automatically if they weren't present.

Comment: If you have linux function app, use `npm install` in settings->configuration->general settings-> startup command and Save. Run the function.

Comment: In my Linux function app there is no "General Settings" under configuration.

In my Windows app there is a General Settings section but it has no Startup section.

Comment: Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71771997/azure-function-general-settings-is-missing#)